# I broke ubuntu - help me reinstall

Tags: login

I have only had ubuntu installed for a few days, completely removing Windows 8. Not knowing what I was doing, I have caused way too many problems with ubuntu and need to reinstall.

The big problem is that I can no longer login. After entering my password nothing happens. I have tried many solutions offered here but with no results.

I do not know how to reinstall from the DVD. Please help.

If it matters, I am using an HP Pavilion G7 AMD. Thanks.

Comment: - At the login screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to the console.
- Log in there.then press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to gui.then try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair .hope this helps.

Comment: i've tried that several times but login screen is still froze after returning via Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: login to the main desktop screen via terminal ...then try boot repair..logging in/out via terminal does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your DVD again and reboot. Thhis wil take you to the live screen (OS running from DVD, not from your hard disk). Then choose Install Ubuntu, then you'll be propted to choose whatever you want to do, you'll have to choose to reinstall Ubuntu completely. That'll make a fresh install, but also that will erase everything you've stored/saved in your HDD.

Comment: i tried that a few times but i am taken straight to the login screen; i know dvd is good because it's what i used to install

Comment: enter BIOS and choose to boot from DVD. It seems that you are not booting from DVD but from your HDD.

Comment: forgive me... i don't know how to enter bios

Comment: With the power off, make sure the power adapter is connected to the computer and plugged into a power source.
Turn on the computer using the power button and immediately press the F10 key repeatedly until a BIOS Setup utility screen appears.

Comment: enter BIOS and choose to boot from DVD. ---figured it out... that did it, thanks!!

Comment: if F10 does not work, try with F11. Don't forget to keep tapping the key until the BIOS screen is shown. Once in BIOS go to the Boot tab and select the boot order, set to boot from DVD first and then press F10 to save and exit. Your device will reboot automatically.

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it worked for you.